# Constraints in prototype cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am beginner in Swift and Xcode and don't can understand constraints in Prototype cells.

I set that Label ("title top news") get place **under** Image.

[image]

But in tests Label get place exactly in center of Image.

[image]

What I do wrong? How doing right and set Label below Image?

Comment: first fix the constants error and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give top, leading & trailing constraints to imageview w.r.t its
   superview.
2. Add height constraint for imageview (if needs to be of
   specific height)Shown in attached image -[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpamO.png)
3. Give leading constraint to label w.r.t its **superview**
4. Give top constraint to label w.r.t **imageview**. Shown in attached image - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KzPA.png)
   Constraints for the table cell will looks like - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL0Jc.png)

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Excuse me, what means is w.r.t?

Comment: W.r.t - with respect to

Answer (score 1):

Constraints for the imageView

> leading ,trailing , top to superView , height (say 200)

Constraints of title

> leading , trailing and bottom to superView ,  top to imageView

Answer (score 1):

you can put the image and the Label in vertical stack

and give them spacing on the attribute inspector.

i hope its help you.